# How to execute a runnable instead of bean creation in Spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

There is a usual configuration creating beans and performing an action using some of them.

The intention of `initialAction` is just execute `print("Hello...")` if certain conditions are in place (MyCondition.class). Obviously this `return null` is only required to keep the ceremony of beans creation and can be misleading for developers reading the code.

Is there a more elegant and convenient way to express the intention "run code after certain beans created if a condition is true"?

```
@Configuration
class App{

    @Bean
    @Conditional(MyCondition.class)
    Object initialAction() {
        var a = firstBean();
        var b = secondBean();

        print("Hello beans: $s, %s".formatted(a, b))

        return null;
    }

    MyEntity firstBean(){
      ...
    }

    MyEntity secondBean(){
      ...
    }

   // other beans
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an annotation [`@PostConstruct`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/annotation/postconstruct) from `javax` or `jakarta` packages that are invoked once the dependency injection is done. Sadly, this cannot be combined with the `@Conditional` annotation.

You can, however, create a dedicated `@Configuration` + `@Conditional` class using `@PostConstruct`:

```java
@Configuration
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public InitialActionConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstBean")
    private MyEntity firstBean;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondBean")
    private MyEntity secondBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        print("Hello beans: %s, %s".formatted(firstBean, secondBean));
    }

    // initializations in other @Configuration class
}
```

Once you do this, both `MyEntity` beans got initialized (if properly defined as beans) and this configuration class autowires them and prints them out only if the condition defined by `MyCondition` is satisfied.